# Conversion rate optimization

Tags: data-visualization, binary-data, discrete-data

The data set [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B5G7QmUBc4IRYUZDS19jS0lUNW8) presents conversion rates of visitors of a website.

Among others, the number of visited pages of the site is a feature and I believe the more pages somebody visits, the more likely she will be a customer.
So how does a discrete value (number of pages) relate to a binary value (customer yes/no)?

When plotting the unique number of pages visited against the accumulated number of conversions, sort of a bell shaped curve emerges:

[image]

Does this kind of visualization make sense? How else could this relationshipt (visited pages -> conversion rate) be visualized?

---

Edit: Alternative summarisation.

When grouping by `total_pages_visited` (i.e. take the pages visits as a factor), a summary can be calculated per the groups.

```
convRate <- group_by(data, total_pages_visited) %>% 
    summarise(conversionRate = mean(converted))
```

This results in a plot where beyond 15 pages visited, every visitor converts to a customer (rate -> 1).

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain the variables in your graphic?  In particular, what is an "accumulated number of conversions"?  How does this graphic give any information about the likelihood of becoming a customer?

Comment: @whuber For example at x=10, the total number of converted visitors is around 700. I.e. out of all visitors who checked 10 pages on the site, 700 in the end became customers.

Comment: Right--but how does that tell you anything at all about "likelihood of becoming a customer"?  You're missing information about how many customers checked out 10 pages.

Comment: In any case, could I conclude that at around 15 pages the conversion is higher than at 10 or 20 pages? As I asked in the question, what other visualizations (concepts) make sense here?

Comment: I don't see any information here whatsoever about conversion *rates*, so such a conclusion would appear to be premature.